# Comparing only one attribute of a structure

Tags: grammar, spin, promela

I got an issue with promela language when trying to compare an attribute, that is not the first one, of my structure.

Here is an example:

```
typedef Msg {
    byte header;
    byte content;
}

chan pipe = [5] of { Msg };

active proctype Receive () {
    Msg r;    
    do 
        :: atomic { (pipe?[1,2])    -> printf("Receive"); pipe?r; } 
        // doesnt compile: :: atomic { (pipe?[-,2])    -> printf("Receive2"); pipe?r; }
        // doesn't compile: :: atomic { (pipe?[, 2])    -> printf("Receive3"); pipe?r; }
        // doesn't works: :: atomic { (pipe?[skip, 2])    -> printf("Receive4"); pipe?r; }
    od        

}



active proctype Emit () {
    Msg m;
    m.header=1; m.content=2; 
    // doesn't compile: m = { 1,2 };
    do 
    :: atomic { printf ("emit\n"); pipe!m; }                                                                                                                                        
    od                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

The problem is very easy: i would like to compare only the `content` attribute. Not the previous one (`header`).
I tried some syntax, take a look at the grammar (http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/grammar.html#recv_args ... btw, i'm not an expert).
But i'm still stuck with this issue.

I use ispin to simulate and test.

Any helps would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a 'generic match character', such as '-', in a `receive`.  So, just declare a variable, as such:

```
active proctype Receive () {
    Msg r;
    byte ignore
    do 
        :: atomic { (pipe?[1,2])    -> printf("Receive"); pipe?r; } 
        :: atomic { (pipe?[ignore,2])    -> printf("Receive2"); pipe?r; }
    od        

}
```

It compiles:

```
$ spin -a foo.ml
$
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But it sounds weird... can you explain me the fact that ``ignore`` which is uninitialized pass the test  ?

Comment: `pipe?[ignore,2]` only requires the `2` to match; `ignore` gets filled in with the value of the first field.